# Motherboard no boot or any fans turning on

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan

Good day everyone!

Yesterday, I brought home my motherboard([biostar H81MG](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=657)) together with the cpu(i5-4440) from my office and tried to make it my gaming mobo and processor. It's like a year old and still working but when I brought it home and tested it using my PSU(I tried a seasonic 500W and evga 500W) and not even a single beep nor the fan and heatsink connected to the motherboard is not turning on.

Everything is in place, the 4-pin and the 20/22 pin is perfectly fit and I even tried removing the ram and other more stuff, I only left the cpu and its heatsink and a single fan. But none of them is turning on.

Is this a Motherboard or CPU problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: These parts new?  Sounds like they are non-functional

Comment: @Ramhound, no they aren't. I've been using those in my office for like a year already and got no problems.

Comment: Have you tried to start the entire process over?  Be sure the motherboard is using the current firmware.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I know if it's using the current firmware? I have tried it over and over again..

Comment: Did you plug in the pins that goto the panel?  Those pins are the ones that actually signal the power supply to start supplying power.  They should look something like [this](http://www.pcstats.com/articleimages/200708/biostarTP35d3a7deluxe_8.jpg).